# How to assign a master to an existant webform?

Tags: webforms, master-pages, asp.net

My friend I are collaborating on a project, he's going to create the Master Page and I'll create the forms.

How can I assign a master page to my existent .aspx form?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the only thing you need to do is have `MasterPageFile` in your page declaration, like so:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" 
CodeFile="ContentPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="ContentPages_ContentPage" %>
```

And, of course, make sure you use the `<asp:Content>` tags to design your page.

```
<asp:Content ID="mainContent" runat=server ContentPlaceholderID=ContentPlaceholder1>
```